# Is there a limit to the number of @extend i can use in Sass?

Tags: sass

I have recently encountered a very strange problem, where i use `@extend .opensans-light;` on a class and it refused to extend the class .opensans-light. No error occurred but when i inspected the element to check if it was successfully extended or not i noticed that it was not added to the list of elements in the .opensans-light class.

```
.opensans-light {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

the @extend was working perfectly up till very recently when i noticed i use @extend on the same class over 100 times. So my question is, is there a limit to the number of times i can use @extend or do i have a different problem ?

Comment: You need to be able to provide enough code to reproduce the problem.  As it stands, I cannot:  http://sassmeister.com/gist/8778f18ce77b0d61921d

Comment: There isn't any more code I can provide its Just the class I'm extending and how I'm extending it and I provided both

Comment: If you can't recreate the problem on Sassmeister (or similar Sass compiling service), the problem doesn't exist and this question needs to be closed.